# Generalization of XOR Linked Lists

Tags: data-structures, reference-request, data-compression, linked-lists, succinct-data-structures

Are there any results generalizing [XOR Linked Lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_linked_list) to other types of data structures?

For example, just like an XOR Linked List requires two pointers and can iterate a 1 dimensional list, I can imagine a two dimensional linked list where nodes are arranged on a plane and connected to eachother vertically and horizontally. Such a "Linked Mesh" can probably be iterated using 4 adjacent pointers in both directions and only storing one or two pointers for each node to its neighbor, instead of the full 4.

Are there any such results or similar results?

Is there a name for these type of structures?

Comment: You could probably apply the technique to any [Zipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_(data_structure)) (a data structure with a 'focus point'). In general I think you can save one pointer. More, if you know multiple outgoing edges or if the edge you entered a node through predicts where you'll exit it.